# get api to fetch the data of US universities

Tags: node.js, database, api

I want to get some API or database for fetching the data of US universities along with the SAT/ACT scores and minimum score of GRE and TOEFL for each university program. I have also looked up for the same on this site and also googled it, i found some database and APIs but none of them is complete. I found the API at [nearbycollege website](https://docs.nearbycolleges.info/) which gives data of SAT/ACT of 2885 schools but I could not find the GRE/TOEFL/GMAT/IELTS exams minimum scores for the same. Kindly help me find that.
  Thanks in Advance
-Bansari

Comment: How is this a node.js problem? Also you seem to have the issue of not finding a link to get the data rather than creating API to GET the data.

Comment: I want API which I can use with my nodejs scripts.